# Need to cut and paste row onto end of previous row

Tags: excel, vba

I am tip toeing into learning VBA for my data analysis work.  I have figured out what I need to do here with multiple "IF" statements and copy and paste but VBA would be much cleaner.

I have many thousands of lines of data from our medical system and they hit Excel as two lines per record.  I would like to take the 2nd line (cells A - J) and cut and paste it onto the end of the first line starting with the first empty cell at J.

I have tried a number of different macros but each one only does one part of what I need and not the entire procedure.  I have not found anyone else who was doing exactly this.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    Sub CutMove()
    '
    ' CutMove Macro
    ' Cut and move 2nd Pt record row to column H of first
    '
    Dim X As Integer
        For X = 1 To 15 Step 3
            Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, 10)).Select
            Selection.Cut
            Range("H" & X).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        Next X
    End Sub

            Sub StackCopy_2()
     For Row = 2 To 15 Step 2
        Range("A3:J3" & Row).Cut
         ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range("J" & Row - 1)
    Next Row
    End Sub
```

***Excel File Snip:***

[image]

Comment: Is this a one-time operation or do you plan to use the procedure on a regular basis?

Comment: This can be easily done. I would like to use ER from column A as an identiifier. Does every record start with it? It would be more correct then using every other row, where the row might sometimes be even, and sometimes odd.

Comment: >Is this a one-time operation or do you plan to use the procedure on a regular basis?  I will be using it on 5 or six different sheets right now, but could see needing to use it in the future if I get requests from the same data source.

Comment: >This can be easily done. I would like to use ER from column A as an identiifier. Does every record start with it? It would be more correct then using every other row, where the row might sometimes be even, and sometimes odd.  Yes, every row starts with ER so that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the sample's data to generate a rudimentary check before copying and clearing. This should probably be adjusted to suit a wider pantheon of actual data.

```
Option Explicit

Sub StackCopy()

    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet9")

        'shuffle data up and right
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row Step 2
            'simple check to see if column A follows pattern
            If Left(.Cells(i, "A"), 2) = "ER" And IsNumeric(.Cells(i + 1, "A")) Then
                .Cells(i, "J").Resize(1, 10) = .Cells(i + 1, "A").Resize(1, 10).Value
                .Cells(i + 1, "A").Resize(1, 10).Clear
            End If
        Next i

        'remove the blank rows
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## Expand Rows

The code is adjusted to copy the result to another worksheet. Try it first like that, and if you're satisfied with the result , change **Target Worksheet Name** (`cTarget`) to the same name as **Source Worksheet Name** (`cSource`). You will have to write the rest of the headers manually though.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExpandRows()

    Const cSource As String = "Sheet1"   ' Source Worksheet Name
    Const cCols1 As String = "A:I"       ' Source 1st Column Range Address
    Const cCols2 As String = "A:J"       ' Source 2nd Column Range Address
    Const cCrit As String = "ER"         ' Source Criteria
    Const cFR As Long = 2                ' Source First Row Number

    Const cTarget As String = "Sheet2"   ' Target Worksheet Name
    Const cTgtCell As String = "A2"      ' Target First Cell Address

    Dim vntS As Variant   ' Source Array
    Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim Nor As Long       ' Source Number of Rows
    Dim Lr As Long        ' Source Last Row Number
    Dim Cols1 As Long     ' Source 1st Number of Columns
    Dim Cols2 As Long     ' Source 2nd Number of Columns
    Dim Cols As Long      ' Target Number of Columns
    Dim i As Long         ' Source Array Row Counter
    Dim j As Long         ' Source/Target Array Column Counter
    Dim k As Long         ' Target Number of Rows,
                          ' Target Array Row Counter

    ' In Source Worksheet (2nd Column Range)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSource).Columns(cCols2)
        ' Calculate Source Last Row Number.
        Lr = .Resize(.Rows.Count, 1) _
                .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious).Row
        ' Copy Source Range to Source Array
        vntS = .Rows(cFR).Resize(Lr - cFR + 1)
        ' Calculate Source 1st Number of Columns.
        Cols1 = .Columns(cCols1).Columns.Count
        ' Calculate Source 2nd Number of Columns.
        Cols2 = .Columns(cCols2).Columns.Count
    End With

    ' Calculate Target Number of Columns.
    Cols = Cols1 + Cols2
    ' Calculate Source Number of Rows.
    Nor = UBound(vntS)

    ' Loop through rows of Source Array.
    For i = 1 To Nor
        ' Check value in current row and first column for Criteria.
        If Left(vntS(i, 1), 2) = cCrit Then
            ' Count Target Number of Columns.
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next

    ' Resize Target Array.
    ReDim vntT(1 To k, 1 To Cols)

    ' Reset Target Row Counter.
    k = 0

    ' Loop through rows of Source Array.
    For i = 1 To Nor
        ' Check value in current row and first column for Criteria.
        If Left(vntS(i, 1), 2) = cCrit Then
            ' Count Target Number of Columns.
            k = k + 1
            ' Loop through Source 1st Number of Columns.
            For j = 1 To Cols1
                ' Write from Source to Target Array.
                vntT(k, j) = vntS(i, j)
            Next
            i = i + 1
            ' Loop through Source 2nd Number of Columns.
            For j = 1 To Cols2
                ' Write from Source to Target Array.
                vntT(k, j + Cols1) = vntS(i, j)
            Next
        End If
    Next

    ' In Target Worksheet (First Cell Address)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget).Range(cTgtCell)
        ' Clear Contents of range from Target First Cell Range to bottom row
        ' and Target Number of Columns wide.
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, Cols).ClearContents
        ' Calculate Target Range.
        ' Copy Target Array to Target Range.
        .Resize(UBound(vntT), Cols) = vntT
    End With


End Sub
```